# Node JS Range Not Satisfiable SendStream.error Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, range

I have this site http://talkwithstranger.com/

I am running it on socket.io and run it via forever js. Forever logs shows the following errors. Can any Node JS expert help me fix these?

```
 Server running at http://localhost:1337/
Server listening at port 9000
RangeNotSatisfiableError: Range Not Satisfiable
    at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/talkwithstranger/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:245:31)
    at SendStream.send (/home/ubuntu/talkwithstranger/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:564:19)
    at onstat (/home/ubuntu/talkwithstranger/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:624:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:117:15)
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

<--- Last few GCs --->

38582463 ms: Mark-sweep 1000.2 (1434.1) -> 983.1 (1434.1) MB, 11363.9 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
38594009 ms: Mark-sweep 983.1 (1434.1) -> 983.1 (1434.1) MB, 11546.2 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
38605768 ms: Mark-sweep 983.1 (1434.1) -> 983.1 (1434.1) MB, 11758.7 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
38617537 ms: Mark-sweep 983.1 (1434.1) -> 982.7 (1434.1) MB, 11768.8 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x3d82e87c9e59 <JS Object>
    1: parse [native json.js:~51] [pc=0x33e240625063] (this=0x682bf036189 <an Object with map 0x1484dab9e839>,x=0x1aa9a1889d31 <Very long string[336563]>,s=0x3d82e8704189 <undefined>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 1->2
    3: decodeString [/home/ubuntu/talkwithstranger/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:327] [pc=0x33e24091ac15] (this=0x3d82e87e40f1 <JS Global Object...

error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGABRT
error: Script restart attempt #2
Server running at http://localhost:1337/
Server listening at port 9000
RangeNotSatisfiableError: Range Not Satisfiable
    at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/talkwithstranger/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:245:31)
    at SendStream.send (/home/ubuntu/talkwithstranger/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:564:19)
    at onstat (/home/ubuntu/talkwithstranger/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:624:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:117:15)
RangeNotSatisfiableError: Range Not Satisfiable
    at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/talkwithstranger/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:245:31)
    at SendStream.send (/home/ubuntu/talkwithstranger/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:564:19)
    at onstat (/home/ubuntu/talkwithstranger/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:624:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:117:15)
RangeNotSatisfiableError: Range Not Satisfiable
    at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/talkwithstranger/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:245:31)
    at SendStream.send (/home/ubuntu/talkwithstranger/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:564:19)
    at onstat (/home/ubuntu/talkwithstranger/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:624:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:117:15)
```

I am a newbie. How can I diagnose these? I am on EC2 and I am upgrading my ram to 14 GB, but i think I have to find and fix these errors somehow.

Comment: DId you ever figure this out? Running into the same thing

Comment: I have same problem here! How to fixed it ?