# Nodejs - Range Not Satisfiable

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

Let me start with a stackoverflow user who had the exact same problem as me(I found him through google):

[Node JS Range Not Satisfiable SendStream.error Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718479/node-js-range-not-satisfiable-sendstream-error-express)

It hasn't been answered, I am guessing many people experience it - why does it happen? I am using NodeJS, express + socket.io, that error gave me no clue and it happened a few times, crashed my server and disconnected my users.
Could it be because:

1) Someone requested a huge file or an object through AJAX/Socket.io(could be in my case)
2) Someone sent a huge string through Socket.io
3) Anything else

Full error:
RangeNotSatisfiableError: Range Not Satisfiable
    at SendStream.error (node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:275:31)
    at SendStream.send (node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:618:19)
    at onstat (node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:677:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
RangeNotSatisfiableError: Range Not Satisfiable
    at SendStream.error (node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:275:31)
    at SendStream.send (node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:618:19)
    at onstat (node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:677:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)

Comment: It means that someone is sending a request with a `Range` header that is unsatisfiable. For instance, the `Range` header is set to `bytes 50-99` but the file being requested is only 40 bytes long.

Comment: If you're using the `serve-static` module then you should probably take a look at its [fallthrough](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static#fallthrough) setting.

Comment: @user still havent found a sol to this problem.